# Set the filter value of a R Shiny Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I would like to know if there is a way to set the values of the filters in a DT datatable programmatically.  The following picture shows a simple datatable with filters. I manually keyed in the filter values on Petal.Length for demonstration. I would like to render the exact same table without having to key in the values manually. Thank you for your input.

[image]

Comment: There's another question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725505/interactive-datatable-keep-column-filters-after-rerendering-the-table?rq=1 In the answer by @kamino17, if you replace '"filter" = c("","","","","")' with '"filter" = c("2.7 ... 5.7","","","","")', it will start a shinydashboard with the table filtering the first column of 2.7-5.7. This has extra features so I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for.